# WPF, TabItem Images

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Have TabControl, which binding to array , need add to TabItem different icons/image. 
haml code:

```
<Grid>
        <TabControl VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Style="{StaticResource TabControl}" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentPage,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItem}" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding HeaderText}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What is the question? What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a ItemTemplateSelector at your TabControl:

```
<TabControl VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Style="{StaticResource TabControl}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentPage,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myItemDataTemplateSelector}" >
```

Your TemplateSelector should look like this:

```
public class MyItemDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is MyItem)
        {
            var myItem = item as MyItem;
            var window = Application.Current.MainWindow;

            switch (myItem.SpecialFeatures)
            {
                case SpecialFeatures.None:
                    return 
                        element.FindResource("Item_None_DataTemplate") 
                        as DataTemplate;
                case SpecialFeatures.Color:
                    return 
                        element.FindResource("Item_Color_DataTemplate") 
                        as DataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx